# Why isn't my application connecting to MongoDB Atlas? How do I fix this issue?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://guest:guest@cluster0.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client["MyDB"]
print(db.list_collection_names())
```

I'm using the Atlas database and I want to store and get data from that database. But for some reason, it's not letting me connect. When I execute the python file, the bash cursor just freezes for several seconds and shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongo.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(db.list_collection_names())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 959, in list_collection_names
    return [result["name"] for result in self.list_collections(session=session, **kwargs)]
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 911, in list_collections
    return self.__client._retryable_read(_cmd, read_pref, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1441, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1257, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 272, in select_server
    server = self._select_server(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 261, in _select_server
    servers = self.select_servers(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 223, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 240, in _select_servers_loop
    % (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description)
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-02.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-01.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-00.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 638931405b2cf5e370bcbc8d, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-00.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-00.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-01.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-01.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-02.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-qymr9hr-shard-00-02.oqhmaiq.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>]>
```

Does anyone who use AWS know what's the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Using the same connection string with `mongosh`, does it work?

Comment: Have you allowed the IP or IP range of your application servers on Atlas side?